# You must issue STARTTLS command first

Tags: java

I am connection to smtp.live.com but when i run program and insert email credentials it asks to use starttls command first what i can do to avoid this exception.

```
try { 
    Socket socket1= new Socket("smtp.live.com",587); 
    again: 
        while(true) { 
            Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in); 
            String from=""; String to=""; String cc=""; String bcc=""; 
            mail[m_count]=new Message();
```

Comment: You could use STARTTLS.

Comment: You somehow need to use SSL. Please show the code you are using.

Comment: try
                 {
              

                     Socket socket1= new Socket("smtp.live.com",587);
 again:
            
  while(true)
  {
   
         
  Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
  String from="";
  String to="";
  String cc="";
  String bcc="";
 mail[m_count]=new Message();

Comment: where i can use ssl n how.....because i have never used ssl before

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 Socket socket1 = new Socket("smtp.live.com", 587);
```

If the port number was 25, that would be fine.  The problem is that you are trying to use SSL enabled SMTP, and that requires that you an SSL socket.  But that is a bit more complicated ...

However, I think that there is a bigger issue here.  The *normal* way to send / receive emails from Java is to use the `javax.mail` APIs.  But if you are opening a socket (or SSL socket) to the mail server, that implies that you intend to implement the client side of the SMTP specification.  Unless you have a really good reason to do that ... it sounds like a waste of effort.

The [tutorial link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) provided by @npinti assumes that you are going to use `javax.mail`.  If you 
want to do it the hard way, [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/0860__SSL-Socket.htm) shows you how to use an SSL socket.